# Show me whether I've answered a question or not

Tags: feature-request, answers

Frequently I see a question that I think I've answered before but I'm not really sure.  This happens when searching for duplicates and when viewing questions that come up in searches.  If my answer isn't in the top 2-3, it may take awhile to determine whether the question is the one I'm thinking of. Obviously, if I'm looking for one I know I've answered and my answer isn't there, the question is the one I was looking for.  I've answered enough questions now that searching through my answers is not a realistic option.

To that end, I'd like some indicator, perhaps located under the "favorite star" to show me when I've already answered a question.  This would be especially useful on questions that have lots of answers, but it would also be a quick indicator as to whether or not I have an answer on a question.

Comment: I think this would be handy too. Doesn't seem terribly onerous to implement either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick fix: scroll to the bottom of the page. If you don't see the answer composition box, instead replaced by "Add another answer", you've already answered the question:

[image: add another answer]

Given that this information is already available, albeit at the bottom of the page, it's only a matter of time before someone Greasemonkeys up an indicator for the top of the page. I do agree, however, that this would be useful as a built-in feature, especially when you're looking at search results and not the question itself.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, but it's still a pain to have to scroll to the bottom.  When obviously the software is aware if I've answered the question or not.

Comment: It's still not visible from the list of questions, which is what [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94658/icon-to-indicate-whether-i-have-already-answered-the-question) was requesting.

Answer (score 2):

You will have an answer composition box at the bottom of the page, unless you have already answered the question, or you were the person asking the question.

If you asked the question, it will have a box that asks if you want to answer your own question.

If you have already answered the question, it will instead ask you if you want to add another answer.

It *probably* won't show you any of these, if the question has been closed.

Comment: Indeed, closed questions don't have the input box.