# How can I easily identify questions that I have already answered or commented on?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, user-interface

I was wondering if there is (or is planned) a feature to know when I already posted a comment and/or answer on a question.

I mean, I often browse tagged questions and I do not always remember if I gave an answer to a particular question.

I think it would be appreciated to have let's say an icon or two to mark commented questions and answered questions by the user in the browsing list.

#### Edit

What about a border around the vote/answer frame in the question list?
Feel free to suggest other UI possibilities.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49174/questions-ive-asked-should-be-optionally-highlighted-as-interesting-even-if-no  (for questions you've asked, not commented/answered)

Comment: Related: [Show me whether I've answered a question or not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13541/show-me-whether-ive-answered-a-question-or-not).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can favorite a question to find it quickly later and be notified of answers.

You can see the questions you've answered in your profile (click on a tag to see the questions in that tag). If you want to know about questions you've commented on, there's no way to make such fine-grained searches in the UI, but you can use the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/) or the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

From the API, you can retrieve the results of a search in a parseable form ([JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)). For all the questions in a tag, use the [`questions` method](http://api.security.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions). For example, [this request](http://api.security.stackexchange.com/1.1/questions?answers=true&comments=true&order=desc&pagesize=100&sort=creation&tagged=cryptography) returns the 100 first questions in the `cryptography` tag on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/), with answers and comments, sorted by creation date. (If you want more than 100 questions, you need to make multiple requests.) From there on, a small script on your machine can extract the questions where you have or haven't participated.

Look around on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) if there's already a browser script or application that might help you.

The data explorer gives you read-only access to a slightly stale copy of the Stack Exchange database. You can make rather complex queries if you know a bit of SQL. For example, I just wrote [Questions I haven't participated in, in a particular tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/it%20security/s/1721/questions-i-havent-participated-in-in-a-particular-tag) (seems to work but I haven't tested much), which you could adapt to “questions I've commented on”.