# Mark questions which got answered by you

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show me whether I've answered a question or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13541/show-me-whether-ive-answered-a-question-or-not)

What do you think about marking question in any way, i.e.

- setting answers count background color
- setting background color
- showing star

on questions that already have your answer?

Comment: What's the additional value of this? I can think of one useful case: When your answer has a huge size, causing your profile pic to be invisible. But, when you create such a large answer, you'll surely identify it as your answer. Not?

Comment: How often do you come across questions you've already answered?

Comment: Also related: [How can I easily identify questions that I have already answered or commented on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89237/how-can-i-easily-identify-questions-that-i-have-already-answered-or-commented-on)

Comment: @RobW: I often want to upvote a good answer and then I find out that it is my own one :-)